# Non-English characters on English Keyboard -

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am looking for a **convenient** way to write Danish Characters on an English and similar keyboard, without changing the layout to Danish, or remembering cryptic sequences.  Normally I use Windows.

There are 3 extra characters, all with uppercase/lowercase versions.

A good solution would be if I have a special mode, which I can easily turn on/off, where 6 adjacent buttons produces these characters.  (or 3 with a shift key).
This could be the  numeric keypad.
(If there is no numeric keypad, I think holding one extra key would be needed.

I often use external keyboard (laptop), so it could be interesting to program one of the keyboards differently.

Less good would be something to click on on the screen, in the browser or on my Android phone.
In that case it should be only my 2*3 extra characters (otherwise it will be to small)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I Use Word 2013's Non-English Character Shortcuts System-Wide?](http://superuser.com/questions/663802/can-i-use-word-2013s-non-english-character-shortcuts-system-wide)

Comment: Windows version? What do you mean normally?

Comment: AutoHotKey may suffice

Comment: @david It is not a duplicate, as I am hoping for something more convenient (it involves 2 extra hits compared to English characters).

Comment: Press one of the five modifier keys ` ' " ~ ^ , then the letter to be modified. ( ' then a = á, " then u = ü, ' then c = ç, etc. ) is two keys?

Comment: How does this work on other keyboards than US?

Answer (score 0):

Download "[Keyboard Layout manager](http://www.klm32.com/)" which is a free software. Install it. Run it as an administrator.

[image]

Double click on your language.

[image]

select one of the keys shown in the image above (such as Ctrl+Alt). Then select one letter from the left side to which you want to assign the character (such as letter k)

[image]

Click on the character map, which is behind the current window.

select a character. You can change subset number on the upper left corner to see more characters.

When you assigned the character, close "character map" window.

[image]

Click OK.

[image]

Close the window.

Restart your PC.

In this case you will be able to type the selected character with Ctrl+Alt+k